# preserving fields collapsed by $group

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to summarize a set of documents by counting on a field named `code`. How can I summarize my data and preserve details from the original documents?

The pipeline input contains the documents below.

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ff38e0eb09dec2cbce14760"), 
    "code" : "U", 
    "date" : ISODate("2021-04-09T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "full_day" : false, 
    "remote" : false, 
    "student_id" : 9441
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ff38e0eb09dec2cbce14807"), 
    "code" : "E", 
    "date" : ISODate("2020-11-02T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "full_day" : false, 
    "remote" : false, 
    "student_id" : 9441
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ff39854b09dec2cbce1494c"), 
    "code" : "E", 
    "date" : ISODate("2020-11-03T08:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "full_day" : true, 
    "remote" : false, 
    "student_id" : 9441
}
```

The desired output groups by `code`, promotes `student_id` to the root level, and nests the other details in a `details` array:

```
{ 
    "code" : "U",
    "student_id": 9441, 
    "count" : 1.0, 
    "details" : [
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2021-04-09T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
            "full_day" : false, 
            "remote" : false, 
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "code" : "E",
    "student_id": 9441, 
    "count" : 2.0, 
    "details" : [
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2020-11-02T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
            "full_day" : false, 
            "remote" : false, 
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2020-11-03T08:00:00.000+0000"), 
            "full_day" : true, 
            "remote" : false, 
        }
    ]
}
```

Combining `$group` and `$push` I've only been able to produce:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "U", 
    "count" : 1.0, 
    "details" : [
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2021-04-09T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
            "full_day" : false, 
            "remote" : false, 
            "student_id" : 9441
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : "E", 
    "count" : 2.0, 
    "details" : [
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2020-11-02T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
            "full_day" : false, 
            "remote" : false, 
            "student_id" : 9441
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2020-11-03T08:00:00.000+0000"), 
            "full_day" : true, 
            "remote" : false, 
            "student_id" : 9441.0
        }
    ]
}
```

The results above were achieved with this pipeline:

```
    [
        { 
            "$match" : { 
                "student_id" : 9441.0
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$group" : { 
                "_id" : "$code", 
                "count" : { 
                    "$sum" : 1.0
                }, 
                "details" : { 
                    "$push" : { 
                        "date" : "$date", 
                        "full_day" : "$full_day", 
                        "remote" : "$remote", 
                        "student_id" : "$student_id"
                    }
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$addFields" : { 
                "student_id" : "$student_id"
            }
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Can we see the aggregation pipeline you used?

Comment: Pipeline added to the original post. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to have different student_id with the same code?  If so, should they be counted together or separately?

Comment: The first step in the pipeline is to `$match` on `student_id`. As such, I don't expect to ever have different student ids enter this part of the pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expect all of the input documents to have the same value for a field, and want that field to be included in the `$group` output, use the [$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#first-aggregation-accumulator) accumulation operator:

```
 { 
            "$group" : { 
                "_id" : "$code", 
                "student_id" : {$first: "$student_id"},
                "count" : { 
                    "$sum" : 1.0
                }, 
                "details" : { 
                    "$push" : { 
                        "date" : "$date", 
                        "full_day" : "$full_day", 
                        "remote" : "$remote"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

If you need to rename `_id` back to `code`, use a `$project` stage after the group.